# How to skip an unwound list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query

```
MATCH (n:Mob)
WITH COUNT(n) as total, COLLECT(n) as nodes
UNWIND nodes as node
WITH total, node
WHERE 8000 < node.order < 8100
RETURN node, total
SKIP 10
LIMIT 1
```

Right now, this query is giving me this error.

[image]

If I remove the SKIP part it works.

So my overall question is, how do I SKIP some of the records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was mainly a misunderstanding on my part. If you want to filter before bunching them together, then perform the `COLLECT` at a later stage.

Working code:

```
MATCH (n:Mob)
WITH COUNT(n) as total, n as node
WITH total, node
WHERE node.order > 1000
WITH total, node
SKIP 10
LIMIT 5
WITH collect(node) as nodes, total
RETURN nodes, total
```